# Exception in hql execution

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hql

I was trying to map a table into entity class and use hql queries on them. I am working in Eclipse and I tried executing HQL queries in Hibernate console. The queries were giving results as expected, but when I deployed my application I got the error :

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
could not initialize a collection: [com.alu.mdm.entities.firmware.FirmwareImage.properties#3014]

     ORA-00904: "PROPERTIES0_"."FIRMWARE": invalid identifier
```

When I saw the sql enabled logs I found the query something like this:

```
select properties0_.FIRMWARE_ID as FIRMWARE4_23_1_,
properties0_.firmware as firmware1_,
properties0_.firmware as firmware19_0_,
properties0_.NAME as NAME19_0_,
properties0_.VALUE as VALUE19_0_ 
from FW_PROPERTIES properties0_ 
where properties0_.FIRMWARE_ID=?
```

I have two tables one is FIRMWAREIMAGE and other is FW_PROPERTIES which looks like this

```
@Table(name = "FIRMWARE_IMAGE",uniqueConstraints=
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"IMAGE_NAME"}))
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "FIRMWARE_IMAGE")
public class FirmwareImage extends PersistentObject {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="FIRMWARE_IMAGE_SEQUENCE")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "IMAGE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
@JoinColumn(name="FIRMWARE_ID")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "com.alu.mdm.entities.firmware")
private Set<FirmwareImageProperty> properties  = new LinkedHashSet<FirmwareImageProperty>();
```

//some getters and setters

My FW_PROPERTIES entity class is like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FW_PROPERTIES", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames=       {"FIRMWARE_ID","NAME","VALUE"}))
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo="FW_PROPERTIES")
public class FirmwareImageProperty extends Persistence implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5574911511734379510L;


@Id
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="FIRMWARE_ID"), @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NAME")})



@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="FIRMWARE_ID" , nullable=false)
@ForeignKey(name="FK_FW_PROPERTIES_FIRMWARE_ID")
private FirmwareImage firmware;


@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Lob
@Column(name="VALUE")
private String value;

  //Some getters and setters
```

My HQL query is "SELECT fw FROM FirmwareImage fw left join fw.properties as fp"

I am not able to figure out why I am getting that exception. Please someone suggest the solution.

Comment: "When ORA-00904 occurs, you must enter a valid column name as it is either missing or the one entered is invalid". Are you sure you have valid column name?

Comment: Maybe you didn't deploy the latest version. The query looks for a  `FIRMWARE` column in table `FW_PROPERTIES` but you don't have (anymore?) such a mapping.

Comment: My table doesn't have the column FIRMWARE . I have not defined it even in the entity class. but still in query it is considering that column. I'm not getting where I have done the mistake.

Comment: How does the table look like on database side? Can you execute `desc FW_PROPERTIES` on the database and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

Move @annotation to getters, for example

```
private String name;

@Column(name="NAME")
public String getName(){
     return name;
}
```